# Law of a random variable

Tags: probability

I have a probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$ with $\Omega=R,F=B(R),P(A)=\int_A xe^{-x}1_{x>0} dx$ for $A \in F$.
I have a function $X:\Omega\rightarrow R$, $X(\omega)=\omega$.
If $Z=1_{X\in(0,2)}-1_{X\in[1,+\infty)}$ prove $Z$ is a random variable and write $Z$'s law.

$Z$ is a random variable because it's a measurable function of $X$.
$Z(\Omega)=\{1,-1,0\}$.
How can I find the law?

Comment: $R$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$ is the power set?

Comment: $B$ is probably" the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to compute $P(Z=1)$, $P(Z=-1)$ and $P(Z=0)$.

Comment: $P(Z=1)=\int_{[2,+oo)} xe^{-x} dx$?